# Using SQS or DynamoDB to control order status

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am building a system that processes orders. Each order will follow a workflow. So this order can be, e.g., booked,accepted,payment approved,cancelled and so on.
Every time a status of a order changes I will post this change to SNS. To know if a status order has changed I will need to make a request to a external API, and compare to the last known status.
The question is: What is the best place to store the last known order status?
1. A SQS queue. So every time I read a message from queue, check status using the external API, delete the message and insert another one with the new status.
2. Use a database (like Dynamo DB) to control the order status.

Comment: What happens after the workflow is completed? Or SNS notification for each stage is enuf?

Comment: Is it okay to have duplicate notifications?

Comment: @Shibashis: After ther worflow is completed I can delete the message from SQS/Database. 
I cant have duplicate notifications.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use the word "store" to describe something happening with stateful facts and a queue.  Stateful, factual information should be stored -- persisted -- to a database.

The queue messages should be treated as "hints" on what work needs to be done -- a request to consider the reasonableness of a proposed action, and if reasonable, perform the action.

What I mean by this, is that when a queue consumer sees a message to create an order, it should check the database and create the order if not already present.  Update an order? Check the database to see whether the order is in a correct status for the update to occur.  (Canceling an order that has already shipped would be an example of a mismatched state).

Queues, by design, can't be as precise and atomic in their operation as a database should.  The [Two Generals Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem) is one of several scenarios that becomes an issue in dealing with queues (and indeed with designing a queue system) -- messages can be lost or delivered more than once.

What happens in a "queue is authoritative" scenario when a message is delivered (received from the queue) more than once?  What happens if a message is lost?  There's nothing wrong with using a queue, but I respectfully suggest that in this scenario the queue should not be treated as authoritative.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with the database option instead of SQS:

1) option SQS:

- You will have one application which will change the status
- Add the status value into SQS
- Now another application will check your messages and send notification, delete the message

2) Option DynamoDB:

- Insert you updated status in DynamoDB
- Configure a Lambda function on update of that field
- Lambda function will send notifcation

  The database option looks clear additionally, you don't have to worry about maintaining any queue plus you can read one message from the queue at a time unless you implement parallel reader to read from the queue. In a database, you can update multiple rows and it will trigger the lambda and you don't have to worry about it.

Hope that helps